# Multipeer-Connectivity Managing Peers Manually

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

According to the Apple`s reference(Managing Peers Manually),I can write my own peer discovery.I don`t want using default peer discovery code,how can I write my own peer discovery code?

Comment: Have you looked at the Multipeer Connectivity Framework documentation?

Comment: Yes ,but I have no idea how to use.I can`t understand the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some guidance in the MCSession documentation:

If you decide to write your own peer discovery code (with NSNetService or the Bonjour C API, for example), you can also manually connect nearby peers into a session. To do this, your app must do the following:

1. Establish a connection to nearby peers and exchange peer IDs with those peers. Each peer should serialize its own local MCPeerID object with NSKeyedArchiver, and the receiving peer should unserialize it with NSKeyedUnarchiver.
2. Exchange connection data. After you have obtained the nearby peer’s ID object, call nearbyConnectionDataForPeer:withCompletionHandler: to obtain a connection data object specific to that nearby peer.
   When the completion handler block is called, send the resulting connection data object to that peer.
3. When your app receives connection data from another peer, it must call connectPeer:withNearbyConnectionData: to add that peer to the session.